# How to define polite and impolite peer in perfect negotiation pattern?

Tags: react-native, webrtc

I see a lot of examples for the "Perfect Negotiation" pattern, but I don't understand how to define the polite and impolite peer? Should I always use for example polite for the peer, which starts the communication? What would be the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign one of the peers to be polite and the other to be impolite. It doesn't matter how you choose them.

For example you might assign a polite role to the first peer that starts the negotiation and impolite to the other. Or do this the other way around.

Or you can generate a random caller id on each side and make it so whoever has the higher id is polite and the other is impolite.

See this explanation in [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Perfect_negotiation):

> How you determine which peer is polite and which is impolite is
> generally up to you. It could be as simple as assigning the polite
> role to the first peer to connect to the signaling server, or you
> could do something more elaborate like having the peers exchange
> random numbers and assigning the polite role to the winner. However
> you make the determination, once these roles are assigned to the two
> peers, they can then work together to manage signaling in a way that
> doesn't deadlock and doesn't require a lot of extra code to manage.

Comment: Oh thanks I somehow did not see this sentence :)